# Extending a forced air heat register

Tags: hvac, ducts

Adding a small room.

Want to extend HVAC to the new room.

[image: What I want]

HVAC guy warned me very expensive for such a small job and told me *(wink wink nudge nudge)* easy to do it myself.

Attic above:

[image: Above]

Question:
The foil ends at the existing register.  Are there any standards I need to adhere to. such as:

- minimum setback from the end of the trunk before I branch off?
- should I just create a "T" junction and lead the foil to the new room?
- do I need special metal fittings or couplers made?

Comment: You don’t want the new register at the end of a trunk. The reason we leave a dead stub on the end of trunks is 2 part. Setting the register back reduces the noise not only from the system but voices from other rooms. The dead airspace also acts as a flow buffer. You may be able to purchase the pieces you need it’s hard to tell with the insulation that is on the pipe

Comment: @Ed Beal Thanks.  Could you point me to some website that documents these concepts in plain English?  My Google fu has not been very good in this area.

Comment: Marinaio, I had this training decades back and don’t remember even the title of the text it was something to the effect of a design guide for the hvac installer. It had the basic forming tools and how to use them. Guides and tables for flows and heat loss today I just go on line for the info from manual J.  I just did a quick search hvac sizing & design by southface (70 slides) may be a quick read to provide an overview, I did not see the tool how two but some basics of flex ducting was in there, with more specific questions I or others may be able to provide answers.